# Why do I have to type "margin-left: 12%" to center my div?

Tags: html, css, center

[image]I manage to center my div (id="div_below_nav") horizontally by typing "margin-left: 12%". From what I understand, divs are usually horizontally centered using "margin-left: auto" & "margin-right: auto". I tried this, but the div shifts all the way to the left. I'm quite confused why this happens and would be glad if someone could explain it for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>CLC Website</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main3.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">

    <div id="nav">
        <img src="../images/logo.png" id="logo" alt="logo">
        <p id="logo_text">CLC</p>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Professors</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Courses</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="welcome_text_div">
        <p id="welcome_text">The Best Offer</p>
        <p id="welcome_under_text">Truth evades a single definition and true
         understanding requires a comparative perspective</p>
    </div>

    <div id="div_below_nav">
    <p></p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>`
```

MY CSS:

```
body {
margin: 0;
background-color: #e7e5e5;
}

ul {
margin-top: -50px;
}

li {
float: right;
font-weight: bold;
}

 li a {
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
font-family: sans-serif;
color: white;
border-right: 1px solid white;
padding: 8px;
}

li a:visited {
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
font-family: sans-serif;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
background-color: #333;
}


#header {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 600px;
background-image: url('bg.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
}

#nav {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
}

#logo {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
}

#logo_text {
position: absolute;
display: inline;
top: -9px;
left: 55px;
font-size: 20px;
font-family: sans-serif;
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
}

#welcome_text_div {
position: absolute;
width: 800px;
height: 300px;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -150px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -400px;
}

#welcome_text {
color: white;
font-family: sans-serif;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 60px;
text-align: center;
}

#welcome_under_text {
color: white;
font-family: sans-serif;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
margin-top: -50px;
}

#div_below_nav {
position: absolute;
width: 950px;
height: 300px;
margin-top: 650px;
margin-bottom: 50px;
background-color: red;
margin-left: 12%;
}`
```

Comment: Divs are usually centered by using `margin: 0 auto;`.

Comment: When I do that, then my div goes to the very top left of the screen.

Comment: try margin left and right auto without the absolute positioning

Comment: You have positioned the `div` absolutely. When doing this, `margin: auto` has no effect anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely positioned elements cannot be centered with the `margin: auto` trick. That is because the browser has no concept of calculating `auto` for them.

Your `div` has a fixed width of 950px. You can leverage that:

```
#div_below_nav {
  left: 50%; /* place left edge in the middle of the parent, then... */
  margin-left: -475px; /* move it half the div's width to the left again */
}

/* or simulate margin:auto with left/right: */
#div_below_nav {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Or you could use `left: 0` `right: 0` as it's a fixed width

Comment: You sir are much smarter than me : )

Comment: @Andy right, that would work, too. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 4):

`margin:auto` works with `position:absolute` if you set `left:0` and `right:0`

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/8Lbku9rc/)

```css
body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        margin: 0;
}

#div_below_nav {
        background: red;
        position: absolute;
        width: 80%;
        height: 50px;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 50px;
        margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="div_below_nav">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using "position: absolute", that means that your position is always absolutely what you tell it to me, no guessing.

Delete that line from your CSS.

If you want to center that div tag, just put a center tag above the div tag. It's easy and efficient and easy to see when debugging. Don't try to make it harder by only using CSS, use what you know works and what works well and what's easy to debug for future debugging.

```
<center>
  <div id="div_below_nav">
  </div>
</center>
```

CSS

```
#div_below_nav {
width: 950px;
height: 300px;
margin-top: 650px;
margin-bottom: 50px;
background-color: red;
}
```

**EDIT**: Although an answer was selected, there are many ways to fix this. One way is to NOT use absolute position in CSS. With that line gone you could use "margin-left: auto".

It's about what will work on the "standard screen size". It's not the same answer as it was 10 years ago and won't be the same 5 years from now. We try to keep up with standards and keep the code as general as possible to encompass many user types. When using resolution absolutes it's a good thing to keep in mind a screen size (width, height) of many potential users.

I use w3schools.com a lot, they always have good answers. Here is a link on screen sizes for today's users as the years pass: http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_display.asp

Comment: unfortunately some handy tags like `<center>` aren't supported in html5 and its use must be discontinued.

Comment: @freestock.tk Really? I just looked into that and it's seems so. It's like what Windows did in 8.1, who needs a start button everyone wants to see a tablet not Windows really. They just deprecate whatever they want anymore. I read the reason and it's not really a real reason it's just a decision. Not everyone adheres to, "If it's not broken don't fix it".

Comment: I have a message on my Chrome that says "sooner you'll not be able to update the browser since the support for your windows (Vista) is going to be discontinued". We are growing old;